# Is it possible to use mulitple possible types in Java?

Tags: java

What I want is a property that is a map with a key of type String, where the value can be either a String OR another map:

```
Map<String, String or Map<String, String>> traits();
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: What is your use case? This and any other key details can make all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it, either your generics or Object.

1. `Map<String, ?> stringObjectMap.get = new HashMap<>();`
2. `Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap.get = new HashMap<>();`

```
if(stringObjectMap.get("key") instanceof Map) return (Map)stringObjectMap.get("key");
        else return (String)stringObjectMap.get("key");
```